# Unknown error while building Xamarin.iOS with XCode 9.2

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios

I have been facing unknown error starting from couple of days ago when I am trying to build my Xamarin.iOS.

I am using VS 2017 v 15.5.5 and Mac machine has Xcode 9.2.
My application is using net standard 2.0.1, Ef Core 2.0.1 .

My approach to solve the problem which didn't:

Remove bin, debug and cache from Mac.
New Xamarin.iOS project

Error:

Error /Users/~/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/~: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets 1868

When I downgraded XCode on Mac to 9.1, building worked fine!
So what is it I am missing or what is the problem with XCode 9.2?

Comment: Try to upgrade your Visual Studio's version both on Mac and Windows.

Comment: My VS on windows is 15,5,6 and on Mac there is no need for VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just moved my build process to AppCenter then I avoided all the wasted time with xcode upgrades.